# VSCode Version Control (git) showing files not in folder

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

I had a workspace of my entire VSCode project directory (all of my unrelated projects) which somehow got version controlled together. I removed that workspace from version control, saved and closed.

Now I create a new project in a new workspace with a new folder and set it up for version control. Except it still uses the project folder with all my projects, NOT the folder I selected for the new workspace.

Is there some default setting overriding this? What is happening?

Help please!

[image: Adding new folder to workspace]

[image: How??]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a .git folder sitting in my root project directory. I had to remove that using the file system. There was no option inside VSCode (that I could find) which could solve this problem.

Apparently it will use any .git folder it finds in the path chain , ie anything in './path/to/folder/'. I erroneously assumed the git folders were somehow keyed to individual projects or files - not the case. Any .git folder in that path to folder will cause this behavior.

Comment: The `.git` folder _is the repo_.